# Repeate Word with Number attached

Tags: python, string

I'm new to python, and want to make something like this in list format so then I can use csv writer.

```
["Structure1", "Structure2", ... "Structure50"]
```

I understand I can use `"Structure "*50` to get Structure repeated 50 times, but how to get it into a list as well as append a number?

Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to make a general comment as this is a very heated thread :-). There are multiple directions you can go with this. Either you are looking for the most readable, or literally the fastest, or even the most memory efficient. It really comes down to what you are after as YOUR answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use a list comprehension and string formatting:

```
["Structure%d" % i for i in xrange(1,51)]
```

Comment: Don't use `%` for string formatting. If *anything* must be used apart from simple concatenation, then use `str.format`.

Comment: This is quite an efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @MarkByers: Why? Because `.format` is cleaner? Faster? This is more efficient than concat

Comment: @jdi: Because `%` is practically obsolete now. `str.format` is its replacement. You can do almost everything with `format` that you can with `%` plus its much easier to read. See Josiah's answer for the best way to do it.

Comment: @MarkByers how so? concatenation is not as efficient as string formatting. http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation

Comment: @JuanCarlosMoreno: Can you try to read what I'm writing, and not what you think I am writing. Please?

Comment: @MarkByers Its not my fault that your comment wasn't very eloquent and the your answer posted, which you later deleted, had a concat. Maybe you should try to communicate clearly next time. :\

Comment: @MarkByers: I agree that the python3.x format might be easier to read, but the python2.x usage of .format is a bit more verbose because you need the kw names.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMoreno: OK I will try to be more eloquent in future! By the way, I don't see why my deleting my answer makes my comments more or less readable since I was comparing jdi's answer (using `%`) to Josiah's answer (using `str.format`). I did try to make that clear by mentioning both `%` and `str.format` in both my comments, but if there was anything more I could do to make it clear that I was comparing using `%` to `str.format`, please let me know. Unfortunately I can't edit my comments, but I can delete them and post them again.

Answer (score 6):

List comprehension:

```
>>> ["Structure{0}".format(x) for x in range(1,51)]

['Structure1', 'Structure2', 'Structure3'... 'Structure50'
```

Comment: This does not work in python2.x:  "ValueError: zero length field name in format"

Comment: If you post a python2.x compat version of this, its faster than mine actually.

Comment: Saying it doesn't work with 2.x is not correct, it works fine in 2.7. I'm assuming you are using 2.6, though I didn't know that was an issue there. I'll change it for portability purposes though.

Comment: Yea I just happen to be on 2.6 at my facility at this moment. If I were at home, I would be testing against 2.7

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here's a solution in a functional style:

```
map("Structure{0}".format, xrange(1, 51))
```

Comment: Speed-wise thats very fast :-)

Comment: @jdi: Also uses the fewest characters (removing spaces)! Although I prefer the list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

This Python statement should serve as a solution:

```
["Structure" + str(x) for x in xrange(51)]
```

Comment: And it uses a string conversion and string concat :-/

Comment: If the OP can't figure out how to get it to show 1-50 instead of 0-49 from this example, he has bigger problems.

Comment: The answer from JDI does not require 3 objects to be created: "Structure", X and then the combination of both. Using formatting is more efficient since python creates less objects.

Also your range starts at 0, and he's asking for it to start at one

Comment: @Falmarri use `join()` instead of `+`

Comment: @JuanCarlosMoreno: Are you saying that with evidence? Or are you just assuming? Do you know for a fact that the internals of the `%` operator do not create more objects than string creation and concatenation of 2 strings? I agree concatenation isn't the fastest when you're concatenating a list into a single string. But I would seriously doubt that the speed difference is significant when concatenating 2 strings into 1.

Comment: Yes its because strings in Python are immutable. But today I also learned that using format is faster than %s :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosMoreno: According to the several timing examples discussed in other comments, string concat is actually the fastest (except the functional .map version). Just because python strings are immutable doesn't mean that `.join`, `.format`, or `%` are doing anything particularly special under the hood.